# React - Understanding checkbox handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this form:

```
construecter() {
    this.state = { dispThumbnails: true };
}

handleChange(event) {
    event.target.value = event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? event.target.checked : event.target.value;
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
}

render(){
     return (
     return (
        <form onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit(event, 1)}>
            <select id='selection' name='selection' value={this.state.selection} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value='Option 1'>Option 1</option>
            </select>
            <input id='subject' name='subject' type='text' value={this.state.subject} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <input id='dispThumbnails' name='dispThumbnails' type='checkbox' checked={this.state.dispThumbnails} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <input type='submit' value="Search"/>
        </form>
    )
}
```

However, the input and select boxes work correctly, but I get unexpected behavior from the checkbox, which is checked by default:

1. First click does nothing, but returns this in the console: "Warning: Received the string `false` for the boolean attribute `checked`. The browser will interpret it as a truthy value. Did you mean checked={false}?"
2. Second click unchecks box
3. Third click checks box
4. Fourth click does nothing, and prints no warning
5. Fifth click unchecks box
6. Sixth click checks box
7. Repeat

Why?  I'm having trouble understanding what's wrong with that.

After additional research and testing I discovered that I can change the form handler to this:

```
handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}
```

And that *does* work as expected, unchecking and checking the box with every click.

But again, why?  I don't see that functionally doing anything different than my original code, other than using a few intermediate variables.

No reason not to use the updated code, but for the sake of learning I'd appreciate if someone could explain why the original example fails as described.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing based on the misspelling of `construecter() {` your state isn't being initialized. Which is why on your first click nothing happens. You are taking the checkbox form an uncontrolled input (because you set `value` to `undefined` because the state isn't set) to a controlled input. I'm not sure why it'd say you are passing a string though, but I'm wondering if this is an artifact of moving from one to the other.

Then this line:

```
event.target.value = event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? event.target.checked : event.target.value;
```

You should not set the value of the target, I'm not sure this is writable. You should make your own variable and work with that.

So on the second click it works because it's now controlled, and again on the 3rd. I'm not sure what is happening after that, but it has to be some side effect of writing to `event.target.value`.

You could simply just do:

```
handleChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? event.target.checked : event.target.value;
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: value
    });
}
```

or

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? event.target.checked : event.target.value
    });
}
```

or your second example is fine. Just don't write to the event's target's value for a controlled component.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  The read-only comment regarding event.target.value makes sense, and your middle code box, which just changes my first example to use a variable for the value, works as expected.  Thanks for clearing this up!